# forward/backward slash problem in wamp

Tags: wamp, slash

I am using a wamp server for development in my windows7 local pc. All my projects are going to be hosted in linux servers and hence I am using "/" as path separator inside php code. But when I take base path it is giving the other slash since I am using in windows. Is there any solution to solve this issue in wamp setting or any other solution?

Comment: Are you storing the base path somewhere or are you getting it from the system when you need it? If the latter, then the path will have the correct slashes when you are using the linux server.

Comment: I am getting in from the system. But currently I am using windows server and I am getting the other slash

Comment: Ok - well when you get it from a linux system the slash will be correct so I wouldn't worry about it. If you do want to test it then you can download something like [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) to run linux on your computer and test your project on LAMP.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to solve this problem by placing the server root as "/". So far that seemed to do the trick.